# Sorting array of Php objects by two fields

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have formed this array of objects using this:

```
foreach($snapdealProductCollection as $snapdealProduct){

            $item = new stdClass();
            $item->id = $snapdealProduct->getId();
            $item->vendortype=2;
            $item->name = $snapdealProduct->getTitle();
            $item->imgsrc = $snapdealProduct->getImageLink();
            $item->price = $snapdealProduct->getEffectivePrice();
            $item->source = "Snapdeal.com";
            $item->redirectUrl = $snapdealProduct->getLink().$affProgram;
            $item->type = $snapedealType[$snapdealProduct->getId()];
            $item->simid = $snapdealsimid[$snapdealProduct->getId()];
            $item->stype = 2;
            $i++;

            array_push($items, $item);
        }
```

I need to sort firstly by type, then by simid. How should I sort it?
Full code:

```
$unsortedItems = $this->getSimilarItems($pid);

    $vendors=$this->getAllVendors();


    usort($unsortedItems , array($this, "cmp"));

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->type, $b->type) || strcmp($a->simid, $b->simid);
}
```

$unSortedItems is the array returned from the foreach block

Comment: With `usort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: i need to sort by two fields?I have this thing: function cmp($a, $b)
 {
     return strcmp($a->type, $b->type);
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `usort()` function for this, and your comparison function should be like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    if(strcmp($a->type, $b->type) == 0){
        if ($a->simid == $b->simid) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a->simid < $b->simid) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return strcmp($a->type, $b->type);
}

usort($unsortedItems , array($this, "cmp"));
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you compare the first field first and the second field second :-)

```
function cmp($a, $b) { 
    return strcmp($a->type, $b->type) || strcmp($a->simid, $b->simid);
}
```

If the first compare returns 0, the second one will be evaluated.
You can write the same longer: if first fields are equal, compare another fields, else return the result of the first comparison.

Comment: doesn't works correctly. Here is the result:                                        sofa----6
 sofa----7
table----2
 table----3
sofa----8
 cushion----9
 table----4
cushion----10     All the sofas should be together,all the table and same for the cushion

Comment: Added in the question